# Cerrar ventana padre desde PopUp en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Que tal, en mi aplicación tengo un botón de Cancelar, cuando se le da clic aparece una ventana tipo Pop Up que pregunta si quiero cancelar o no, al dar clic en si, debe cerrar la ventana Pop Up y la ventana en la que estaba y mandarme  al Home, lo hace, pero no cierra la ventana padre del Pop Up, tienen alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo? Estoy utilizando WPF y el patrón MVVM.

Este el les código del botón:

```
private void btn_yes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Proyecto.Desktop.View.HomeView newWin = new HomeView();
        Proyecto.Desktop.View.ParentWindow parent= new ParentWindow();

        parent.Close();
        newWin.Show();
        this.Close();                                                       
     }
```

Gracias, Saludos!

Comment: Hmm..solo viendo que usas el evento `Click` me parece que no estas siguiendo correctamente el patrón MVVM...

Comment: @Pikoh cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo? Soy nueva utilizando MVVM

Comment: Bueno, ahora que lo pienso podría caber dentro de MVVM ya que lo único que haces afecta a la vista y no al modelo. Voy a darte una respuesta de todas maneras a ver si resuelve tu problema

Comment: 2 formas

1- Perfectamente puedes utilizar una clase de tipo interface, poner un metodo que al llamarlo cierre la ventana que quieres e implementarlo en ambas ventanas.. entonces en vez de cerrar la ventana llamarás a la interface que estará por sobre la ventana padre y la cerrará..

2 - Declara la ventana padre como estática, en una clase también estática, de ese modo solo la instanceas cuando la uses y puedes cerrarla desde cualquier parte sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que haces esto:

```
Proyecto.Desktop.View.ParentWindow parent= new ParentWindow();
parent.Close();
```

`parent` es **una nueva instancia de ParentWindow**, no la que ya está activa y que quieres cerrar. Puedes intentar buscarla y cerrarla si la encuentras. Sería algo asi:

```
var parent= Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ParentWindow>().FirstOfDefault();
if (parent!=null)
{ 
    parent.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declara la ventana "padre" en una clase estática pero no la inicialices, puedes hacer lo mismo con el Dialog

```
public static class GlobalDialogs
{
    static ParentWindow _parentWindow;
    public static ParentWindow ParentWindow
    {
        get { return GlobalDialogs._parentWindow; }
        set { GlobalDialogs._parentWindow = value; }
    }

    static PopUpDialogWindow _popupDialog;
    public static PopUpDialogWindow PopupDialog
    {
        get { return GlobalDialogs._popupDialog; }
        set { GlobalDialogs._popupDialog = value; }
    }

}
```

En la ventana 'padre' (parent) que necesites abrir el popup hazlo así

```
public void AbrirPopup()
{
    if (GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog == null)
    {
        GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog = new PopupDialog();
        GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog.Closed += (a, b) => GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog = null;
        GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalDialogs.PopupDialog.Show();              
        //GlobalDialogs.Topmost = true;  // important
        //GlobalDialogs.Topmost = false; // important
        //GlobalDialogs.Focus();
    }
}
```

Ahora cuando necesites cerrar la ventana padre desde el PopupDialog solo cierra la instancia creada en la clase estática desde el mismo popup

```
public void CerrarParent()
{
    if (GlobalDialogs.ParentWindow != null)
    {
        GlobalDialogs.ParentWindow.Close();
    }   
}
```

Otra opción es usar una clase tipo interface y poner un metodo de cierre en ella